# Can't register with Stack Exchange

Tags: support, user-accounts

I am trying to register an account with Stack Overflow, but the confirmation emails do not appear to be sending correctly - I have made multiple registration attempts, from multiple email addresses with different providers, over a period of several weeks, and have checked the junk folders for all those email addresses, without ever seeing any emails from Stack Overflow at all.

I also tried registering directly at https://openid.stackexchange.com/account/register/submit but again have had no email come through. In each case, I submit the registration form and get the "registration email sent to .... Open this email to finish sign-up" message, but then nothing.

I can (obviously) use an OpenID account from elsewhere, but that's not what I want to do - I want to create an actual Stack Exchange account. Can anyone see any reason I might not be getting these emails?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this - getting an email immediately. Getting the "registration email sent to" message means that the email was sent out of our system - unless the email addresses are malformed or nonexistent, I don't see why you wouldn't be getting them.

Comment: Can you provide more information? What browser/OS are you using? Did you try different browsers? Do you use any extensions/add-ons/plugins/user scripts? If so, can you try to disable them and register? Do you see any errors in the developer tools console?

Comment: I tried in Windows / Firefox, Windows / IE, and Linux / Firefox. My Firefox on both OSes does have a variety of add-ons etc, but the IE is the plain version. I will try again and check the dev tools.

Comment: Just for completeness sake - the emails do not come from Stack Overflow or the `stackoverflow.com` domain. They come from the `stackexchange.com` domain - the email title will be "Complete Registration on Stack Exchange". Did you check for those?